# Is Shodan, the IoT search engine, really reliable?

Tags: shodan

As far as I can see, [Shodan](https://www.shodan.io/) seems to be choosing the IP and ports randomly from a list. Is this really the best way to scan the entire internet for IoT devices?

Comment: How else would you go about it? You can crawl HTTP, which has hyperlinks. How else would you find  IoT devices, other than brute force (ouch! for IP v6) - unless you know that a manufacturer was allocated a block of fixed IP addresses, which seems unlikely.

Comment: I know brute forcing is the almost only option, but I was more asking about the random part.

Comment: If it chose ports sequentially, it would be far easier for manufacturers to recognize a Shodan scan in their firmware and block it. The randomization is an effort to obfuscate the source of the HTTP query, which in turn makes it harder to recognize as a scan or intrusion attempt, which in turn (theoretically) makes the resultant data set more reliable.

Comment: That is an execllent point. Maybe worth posting as an answer? Otoh, that extra code to check, and storing the data may be too much for soem small devices. It _could_ make a good FOSS (or even commerical) product, though.

Comment: @WayToDoor  Random - I see. Nope, I can’t think of a reason for that. Otoh, you might be able to make it slightly more efficient by ***excluding*** ranges of addresses, such as those known to be allocated to major ISPs.

Comment: This question provides no information about what Shodan does or what the goal of that search really is. Thus, I vote to close for no prior research and being too broad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of unclear goal and no prior research.

Comment: Reliable for what? For finding all devices in a particular domain? For finding all devices of a certain type? For detecting whether a particular device is visible from the Internet? etc.

Comment: This is more of a networks question than an IoT one

Answer (score 8):

In order to scan the entire Internet, you need to scan the *entire* Internet: every combination of IP address and port. Further, you need to do it in a way that hides what you're doing, so you don't get blocked.

A simple sequential scan is the obvious way to do it, but a sequential scan is trivial to spot.  Instead, Shodan scans in an apparently-random pattern (a *permutation* of the complete list of address/port combinations), and does so from a wide range of source addresses. Doing this means it takes longer to say that a given address does (or does not) have an IoT device on it, but it also makes the scan look more like the random noise of the Internet.